# Why would a Publish transaction change from "Transport service unable to transport" to "Success"?

Tags: tridion

Sometimes when mass publishing there will temporarily be failed items with the error

> Transport service unable to transport

Refreshing the Publish Queue a few times will then result in a success being returned. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd assume that once a publish transaction reaches an error state it will be "beyond repair". But clearly that is not happening in your case. The fact that you reload the transactions in the Publish Queue window has no effect on what the publisher does, so it is most likely that the publisher and transport service are still working on the transaction.

My advice would be to switch the log level of the transport service to DEBUG and see if anything related to these transactions shows up in there.

Comment: Are you sure it is actually the same transaction? If the same item is put in the queue with the publishing target, and it reaches one of the 'final' states (like Error or Success), it will replace the one that has an 'Error' state.

Comment: Yes - I think Quirijn has it. It is a different publish transaction. @Quirijn - I think you should make this an answer rather than a comment

Answer (score -1):

As addon to Frank answer, check the transaction folder is empty or transport packages are still lying on this folder.

It seems transport packages are unable to unzip the data.